# How to remove image using vueclip

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using the component [vueclip](http://vueclip.adonisjs.com/#-events)
the only thing that I need to do is to render after an image has been deleted,

I'm not sure if what I did is correct, basically I try to pass the id to an click event and remove from the array..

```
<template>
   <vue-clip :options="options" :on-added-file="addedFile" :on-init="init">
      <template slot="clip-uploader-action">
        <div>
          <diventer code here>
            <h2> Click or Drag and Drop files here upload</h2>
          </div>
         </div>
       </template>

       <template slot="clip-uploader-body" scope="props">
         <div class="uploader">
           <div v-for="(file , i) in props.files">

             <figure>
                <img v-bind:src="file.dataUrl" />
                <figcaption>      
                  <span><button v-on:click="removedFile(i)">x</button</span>
                  </figcaption>
                </figure>
              </div>
              </div>
            </template>

          </vue-clip>


        </template>
```

**js**

the code commented is an example from the component,

```
data () {
    return {  
      options: {
        url: '/',
        paramName: 'file'
      },

      files: []

    }
},
 methods: {
   removedFile (index){  
     return this.files.splice( index, 1)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is `removedFile` in the `methods` object?

Comment: in the doc is passed like this "<vue-clip :on-removed-file="removedFile">
  </vue-clip>" but I just dont understand how is going to be trigger. that's why I use a simple click event.. my thought was to remove the item from the array and vue would do the magic and remove it from the DOM but this is where I'm stuck now

Comment: I'm saying the code you've shared for your Vue instance is not valid. `removedFile` should be inside the `methods` object. Is that the case in your code and you didn't copy it over?